# Read certain info from xml file using python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am new to `xml` and have a little experience with python.
I am trying to use python's `xml.etree.ElementTree` module to parse `xml` file.
Using `print(info.text)`, it can print out all the elements in the `xml` file such as `WIL-RT2`, `Rtr_Cisco`..., but I would like to retrieve only `WIL-RT2` and then based on `WIL-RT2`, I can return the `Rtr_Cisco`.
Here is part of my `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<model-response-list xmlns="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response" total-models="115" throttle="115" error="EndOfResults">
<model-responses>
<model mh="0x700e8f">
<attribute id="0x1006e">WIL-RT2</attribute>
<attribute id="0x10000">Rtr_Cisco</attribute>
<attribute id="0x12d7f">172.20.111.252</attribute>
<attribute id="0x12bfb">NAT,192.168.249.150</attribute>
<attribute id="0x100ae" error="NoSuchAttribute"/>
<attribute id="0x100af" error="NoSuchAttribute"/>
</model>
</model-responses>
</model-response-list>
```

Here is my python code

```
for item in root.findall("{http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response}model-responses"):
     #print(item.findall('{http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response}model'))
     for child in item.findall('{http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response}model'):
         #print(child.attrib, child.tag)
         for info in child.findall('{http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/response}attribute'):
               print(info.tag, info.attrib)
               print(info.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is method to get the text.
here is the code
print(info.findtext("[@id='0x1006e']"))